# AngularJS - ui-date textbox editable

Tags: angularjs, uidatepicker

I am using `ui-date` in `AngularJS`.

```
<input name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth" type="text" ng-model="search.dateofbirth" ui-date="dateOptions" ui-date-format="mm/dd/yy">
```

When I click on the `textbox`, a calendar pops up, but the user cannot type in the `textbox`.

How can I make this textbox editable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this directive, when you click on the text field calendar should be shown.. Here is the working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/nabeezy/HB7LU/209/

```
myApp.directive('calendar', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
                $(el).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    onSelect: function (dateText) {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            ngModel.$setViewValue(dateText);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    })
```